# Having trouble passing back values in the function for items

Tags: javascript, function

This code was created to pass back values upon purchase. All information above the items section is properly populating. order.current.items references code on the site that houses id, special_price, qty but for some reason, it is not populating into the function.

```
<script>
    window.liQ = window.liQ || [];
    window.liQ.push({ 
        event: "conversion",
        name: "product_purchase",
        transactionId: "[[Checkout Success | Order | Increment ID]]",
        amount: "[[Checkout Success | Order | Subtotal]]",
        currency: "USD",
        emailHash: "[[Checkout Success | User | MD5 Hash]]",
        items: function() {
            var pl = [];
            var orderItems = order.current.items;
            for (var i = 0; i < orderItems.length; ++i){
                pl.push({
                    id: orderItems[i].id,
                    price: orderItems[i].special_price,
                    quantity: orderItems[i].qty
                });
            }
            return pl;
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: items here is a function which returns array of items not the array of items itself. I'm not sure, but I think you should use self-execute function instead.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are simply saying that `items` is a function. You don't actually execute it though. One solution:

```
items: (function() {
          var pl = [];
          var orderItems = order.current.items;
          for (var i = 0; i < orderItems.length; ++i){
            pl.push({
              id: orderItems[i].id,
              price: orderItems[i].special_price,
              quantity: orderItems[i].qty
            });
            }
            return pl;
          }})();
```